# How can I search in Label[] for item.Text?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new to programming so I guess this question is kinda stupid. I want to check if current Text exists in `Array` of `Labels`, because I get same name twice sometimes.

```
for (int i = 0; i < DM.checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
{
    labels[i] = new Label();
    for (int j = i; j < DM.dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        if (DM.dataGridView1.Columns[j].Visible)
        {                        
            if (labels.Contains(DM.dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText))
            {
                labels[i].Text = DM.dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can use `bool exists = labels.Any(l => l.Text == searchText);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know if array of labels contains particular text, you need to search through their `Text` property:

```
labels.Select(l => l.text).Contains(DM.dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText)
```

I used `Select` LINQ extension method to change array of `Label`s into array of `string`s.